# How do I make a website automatically display files from a file structure?

Tags: php, javascript, html, file-upload, directory-structure

I'm currently creating a website as part of a high school internship for a professor as a university.

Since he is constantly uploading new assignments, I am wondering if there is a way that I can `php` or `JavaScript` to automatically add files inside the webpage.

To go into description of my concept, there is a set file structure for the professor's website. The website correlates with that file structure but every time he adds a file he has to go into the code and link it.

I know this would be easy with `Dreamweaver`, but I want to make the process speedy for him. I want to have it so that he adds a file to the structure and the website automatically adds the name of the file within the webpage and makes a link to download it. I know nothing about `PHP` but I am familiar with `JavaScript`, just not with integrating it into `HTML`.

Comment: If you're not opposed to an out-of-the-box solution, I've deployed a few sites of this sort using WordPress ([http://wordpress.org/](http://wordpress.org/)) and the List Yo Files plugin ([http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/list-yo-files/](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/list-yo-files/)). This allows you to easily create pages that always pull the freshest file list. And you can use FTP, if you like, to manage the files themselves.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is a friendly site for asking specific questions, and receiving specific answers to programming issues. Your question is overly broad in that it asks for how to create an entire application, and it could be easily answered by just making a Google search for the keywords in the title. Please come back when you have started programming something, we'll be glad to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [readdir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php) function for php.

```
//Example #2 List all entries in the current directory and strip out . and ..
<?php
if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
            echo "$entry\n";
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

Now you could change the `opendir('.')` part to match any directory available to the webserver. And instead of just echo you can output htmlcode that links to the file.

Comment: Does this method work offline? I currently don't have the website on a server yet. I added the code and changed the directory but I am not getting any output. Also, I have no idea what you mean by changing echo.